# Checkin Policy not working after upgrading to VS 2015

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

We are running VS2013, along with VSTS for source control. We have a checkin policy that enforces a checkin Comment and for the user to assign a Work Item(s) to the checkin. This has been working fine as expected for a while.

[image]

Recently, I got one of the developers to test VS2015 Update 1. He is now reporting to me that the checkin policy doesn't seem to work properly; even though he correctly adds a Comment and assigns a Work Item for the checkin, the system doesn't seem to recognise them and it gives a 'policy failure' warning like this:

[image]

Is this a known bug with VS2015? Or some sort of compatibility issue upgrading from 2013 to 2105?

Comment: Did you update the checkin policy file so that it can be used in VS2015?

Comment: Hi Eddie, I did not do any such update of the policy files? How do you do that? I still have a few devs working with VS2013 until we are happy that VS2015 is stable enough - this little quirk is the only thing stopping us from moving everyone over.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the actual policy failure message? The second screenshot above is the Override message and NOT the Policy warning...

Comment: Hi Mr Hinsh, I got the user to recreate the issue and I see 2 extra messages (see comment below).

Comment: Internal error in Changeset Comments Policy. Error loading the Changeset Comments Policy policy (The policy assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.CheckinPolicies.ChangesetComments, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not registered.). Installation instructions:

Internal error in Work Items. Error loading the Work Items policy (The policy assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not registered.). Installation instructions:

Comment: Any news on this? Got the same problem with Redgate Source Control

Answer (score 0):

Install [2015 Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) on the client PC.  Your Power Tools version has to match your Visual Studio Client.

Comment: Hi M Tovbin, I already had TFS 2015 Power Tools installed on the client PC

Comment: I am not able to re-create your issue with VS2015 Update 1 and VSTS.  Can you post a screenshot of the Team Explorer Pending Changes with your work item associated.

Comment: On further investigation, it seems like its only related to checking-in with the TFS Power Tools in Windows Explorer (checking-in in VS work fine) and it seems like it is a version mismatch issue with the check-in policies originally created in TFS 2013, and then attempting to upgrade only one user to TFS 2015.  am going to upgrade all users to TFS Power Tools 2015 first, then re-do the checkin policies to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Update: I tried removing the checkin policies, closing and retarting Visual Studio, then re-adding them back in using VS / Power Tools 2015, but still get the errors indicated here:

Comment: Internal error in Changeset Comments Policy. Error loading the Changeset Comments Policy policy (The policy assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.CheckinPolicies.ChangesetComments, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not registered.). Installation instructions: 

Internal error in Work Items. Error loading the Work Items policy (The policy assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not registered.). Installation instructions:

Answer (score 0):

In the past years, we also had to update our check in policies, from 2013 to 2015.

Here is somethings you may check.

1. Recompile your CheckInPolicy project updating Visual Studio Assemblies references:

   - Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
   - Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
2. Register your Policies:

   - [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies]
     `"YourCheckInPolicies"="PathToYourCheckInPolicies.dll"`
   - [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies]
     `"YourCheckInPolicies"="PathToYourCheckInPolicies.dll"`

Hope it helps.
Regards,
Wilsade

Answer (score 0):

The company I'm working at changed our PCs and we had the same problem when we needed to install VS.NET 2015 for some old projects.

I simply copied the below directory's content (from an old PC where policies worked) and placed it in the same directory, in the new PC.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`

If the directory `Team Explorer` doesn't exists, create it manually and put the content into it.

OBS: When I did it, I already had VS.NET 2015 Power Tools installed.

So, try to solve it with these two steps:

1. Install Power Tools to VS.NET 2015 as mentioned in the other answers.
2. Copy necessary DLLs files to `Team Explorer` directory. I made a copy of them [here](https://dropmefiles.com/zEdlH).

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV1lW.png) was my registry after installed Powetools, and because of that I tried to paste files manually... I got lucky. It worked.